# Testing Parse Server Cloud Code on Node.js fails "Parse.Cloud.beforeSave is not a function"

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I'm attempting to implement automated tests in my parse server repository that I run in node.js in my development environment. However, it appears that some of the functions available in the parse cloud code SDK are not available in the NPM parse library. In particular, test code imports

`Parse = require('parse/node');`

And then my code calls `Parse.Cloud.beforeSave`. This causes the error  `Parse.Cloud.beforeSave is not a function`. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

I published an NPM library called [parse-node-with-cloud](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-node-with-cloud) that provides a `Parse.Cloud` object in node.js. I hope this will enable node.js unit tests of Parse cloud code.

===========

My solution to this is to use the [parse-cloud-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-cloud-express) library on NPM. Import it with

`const Parse = require('parse-cloud-express').Parse;`

Then Parse.Cloud functions will work as expected.

Unfortunately, the source code is no longer available on github and the module is likely no longer maintained.